# SQL How to generate schedules for appointments based on some criteria?

Tags: sql, postgresql, scheduling

I'm creating a project to schedule times for customers of a barbershop.

The services provided for example are:

```
  name              service_time
______________________________
| Haircut         | 00:30:00 |
| Beard           | 00:15:00 |
| Eyebrow         | 00:45:00 |
------------------------------
```

I created a function in the Postgres database, to generate the times I have available to display to the client.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION free_hours(start_work TIME, start_launch_time TIME, stop_launch_time TIME, stop_work TIME)
RETURNS TABLE(step INTERVAL, free_hours TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE)
AS $$
  SELECT step::INTERVAL, free_hours FROM
  UNNEST(ARRAY ['15 min', '30 min', '45 min', '60 min']) AS t(step)
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL
  GENERATE_SERIES(
     '2021-10-20'::date + start_work,
     '2021-10-20'::date + stop_work + INTERVAL '1 day',
     step::INTERVAL
  ) AS free_hours
  WHERE free_hours::TIME NOT BETWEEN start_launch_time AND stop_launch_time
  AND free_hours::TIME >= start_work AND free_hours::TIME <= stop_work
  AND EXTRACT(dow FROM free_hours) <> 0 -- Sunday
  AND free_hours NOT IN (
    SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(
      a.created_at::TIMESTAMP - (step::INTERVAL - '1 min'::INTERVAL)::TIME,
      a.created_at,
      INTERVAL '1 min'
    ) as hours_to_remove
    FROM appointments a
    INNER JOIN services s ON a.service_id = s.id
  )
  AND free_hours NOT IN (
    SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(
      a.created_at,
      a.created_at::TIMESTAMP + s.service_time::TIME - '00:01:00'::TIME,
      INTERVAL '1 min'
    ) as hours_to_remove
    FROM appointments a
    INNER JOIN services s ON a.service_id = s.id
  )
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
```

This function, it generates available times for scheduling following some rules such as:

- Display only schedules based on the start and end of the working day
- Does not list times when the barber is at lunchtime
- Does not list times on Sunday

And another validation that is done by this function, it is based on the time the customer has chosen, it is responsible for generating 2 new series, which serves to help not run the risk of an available time appearing, when the barber is with some client, that is, he guarantees that the chosen time will not have interference from other times.

---

This function is doing what needs to be done, but I may have made a mistake with it, in it I generate the schedule for all the service times that exist: **15min**, **30min**, **45min** and **60min**, these times are generated sequentially eg: 15min in 15min and so on.

But the problem that's occurring to me and I'm not being able to solve it would be when the following case happens eg:

I booked a **Haircut** at **09:30**, this cut has a duration of **30min**, ending like this at **10:00h**, so at that time I would be able to schedule one for example. **Eyebrow**, which lasts **45min**, but the way I did it, as the timetables in the case of 45min go from 45min to 45min, the problem that will happen is that the time of 10am will not be available for me to mark, this example would only be available at 10:30

Could someone help me? I really couldn't think of another way to make this listing without applying these rules.

Link for creating tables and function, insert and select: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wMK5BP1oXZPdj4Bp1CxWLp/0

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest :

1. to not create several steps, but only the least common one, eg 15 minutes
2. to work with range of timestamps using the data types tstzrange and calculate differences of ranges by using a specific function such as :

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION range_diff (x anyrange, y anyrange)
> RETURNS setof anyrange LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
> $$
> BEGIN
> CASE
> WHEN x @> y
> THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT tstzrange(lower(x), lower(y)) UNION SELECT tstzrange(upper(y), upper(x)) ;
> ELSE RETURN QUERY SELECT x - y ;
> END CASE ;
> END ;
> $$
> ```

3. To manage the daily schedule as a range, eg

> `tstzrange('20211101 090000','20211101 170000')`

for the 1st of Nov 2021 from 9.00AM until 5.00PM

4. To calculate the booked timeslot in the appointement table based on the start time and the duration of the selected service, eg

> `tstzrange('20211101 094500' :: timestamp with time zone,'20211101 094500' :: timestamp with time zone + INTERVAL '45 MINUTES')`

for an eyebraw starting at 09.45AM the 1st of Nov 2021

5. to remove the booked timeslot from that schedule, eg

> ```
> range_diff (tstzrange('20211101 090000','20211101 170000'),tstzrange('20211101 094500','20211101 103000'))
> ```

in order to calculate the free ranges of time available once the eyebraw service is booked at 09.45AM. The result is :

> ```
> ["2021-11-01 09:00:00+01","2021-11-01 09:45:00+01")
> ["2021-11-01 10:30:00+01","2021-11-01 17:00:00+01")
> ```

6. When you create a new appointement, you can check if it can be inserted in the schedule or not, ie it is contained in a free range

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't know if this solves my problem, I don't have much knowledge with SQL, but I need to generate a complete list with the available times, with the query I made I generate it normally, but the problem I mentioned above occurs, Could you show me an example generating this list of times based on what you said? because from what I tested I couldn't play the list, but a range only.

Comment: No, I propose to proceed as the opposite : you provide me an extract of your tables 'services' and 'appointements', with the table structures (CREATE TABLE services AS ...) and with the insert statements (INSERT INTO TABLE services VALUES (...), (...), ...). Then I can give you more guidelines.